# Codeigniter form validation, which rule triggered?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

When `form_validation->run()` returns `FALSE`, I need to know which rule didn't pass the validation test.
I know I can echo `form_error()` or `validation_errors()`, but this needs to be done before a view is loaded.
The controller needs to act differently according to which input didn't pass the validation.

Example:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $this->load->view('something');
    }
    else
    {
        //check which rule didn't pass and act accordingly
    }
}
```

I tried using `empty` on `form_error('something')` from within the `if` statement but this returns an error as `empty` doesn't take functions.
Also note, I can't change the error delimiters because they are used elsewhere in the script.

How would I check which rule was triggered without echoing `validation_errors()`?

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN USE error() for this-

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
     $this->load->view('something');
    }
    else
    {
         print_r($this->form_validation->error());
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't display anything. Where can I find this in the documentation? I couldn't see it in the form validation section

Comment: yes. its a function in form validation class. go to system/libraries/form_validation.php and search for error(). You will find it there

Comment: Or you can even get an array of errors. see this- http://darrenonthe.net/2011/05/10/get-codeigniter-form-validation-errors-as-an-array/

Answer (score 0):

To display an error message using a specific field 
form_error('username')